# Is there a way to link to the middle of someone else's page even if they don't have an anchor?

Tags: javascript, html

...something along the lines of telling the browser which percent of the page to center to?

Comment: I think that any way you do it, you will need to edit the "other" page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can.  If the person has an element with an ID anywhere on the page. For example:

```
<div id="someId"></div>
```

Then you can create a link to this page like:

```
<a href="http://somePage.com#someId">Middle!</a>
```

The only thing you need to do is choose an Id in the middle.

Comment: This also a great alternative too from this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703136/13642249)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this without anchors.  You would need to access the DOM in order to do a scrollTo or something like that, which is prohibited on different domains.  Security being the main reason.

Comment: Turns out that the #hash stuff can target *any* element with an "id" value.  It freaked me out when I learned that too because apparently it's been true in browsers for a really long time; even IE6 understands it.

Comment: Neat and weird at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

{using Google Chrome web browser; ***remeber wiki is dynamic and the following URL may get invalid at anytime, the process is still valid though!***}

1_ This is the main URL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

2_ I want to refer to "A worked example" in the middle of the page

3_ right click on "A worked example" -> Inspect Element -> Edit as HTML

4_ you should see this:

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="A_worked_example">A worked example</span>
```

5_ The id is **id="A_worked_example"**. Copy-paste it in the following sentence as follows:

`<a href="http://somePage.com#someId">Middle!</a>` :

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#A_worked_example">Middle!</a>
```

6_ There you go:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#A_worked_example

:)