# Linking to arbitrary content on a webpage without anchor tags

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm looking for a way to link to a specific range of words, image or other arbitrary content on a web-page. One alternative is to introduce tons of anchors on the page, but I can live with a solution that requires JavaScript. Preferable also one that highlights the target content.

It would also be great to have some kind of protection (in the form of an alert warning) if the content of the page has been modified, and the link is no longer valid.

Does anyone know of a library that handles this, or have any advice on what to look at? I assume there is no W3C standard that enables an URL scheme for arbitrary direct linking without introducing anchors (name tags)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you are working on and what you have tried?

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery?  You can automatically assign anchors to your keywords with a little scripting.

Comment: @Tanner my only idea so far, is to create a visual tool (addon or bookmarklet) that enables users to create anchors. This anchor is then converted to a CSS selector that is passed as a fragment identifier, and some JS that translates that to a location on the page. Also got some idea on a cyclic redundancy check to ensure that the content isn't modified. But it's only ideas for now.

Comment: @SableFoste Yes, maybe thats a good idea. I was actually thinking of doing some JS to scroll it into viewport myself.

Comment: If the user is creating the anchor, just wrap that text/object/whatever in a <div> or another element that meets your symantic needs. Give that <div> an id that will work for your css selector and (as of HTML5) as an anchor for a link as the HTML5 spec does away with using the <a> tag to create anchors and uses it instead for creating hyperlinks only.

Comment: @ReidJohnson I don't want to modify the source HTML. It need to work on generic pages, only with injected javascript code

Comment: That would be why you use the javascript to alter the DOM dynamically, not change the actual source code.

Comment: @ReidJohnson yes, I completely agree with you.

Comment: It looks like jQuery's wrapSelection plugin would do you a world of good. Details here [link](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/wrapSelection)

Comment: Why not this little jQuery plugin? http://briangonzalez.org/arbitrary-anchor?

Comment: @briangonzalez Brian, if you post that as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer. Ty Sir

Answer (score 15, accepted):

7 years later and it is 2020, there is a draft now by WICG for **[Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/#indicating-the-text-match)**, and now you can link to text on a page as if you were searching for it by adding the following to the hash

`#:~:text=<Text To Link to>`

Working example on `Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138`:

[Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338602/linking-to-arbitrary-content-on-a-webpage-without-anchor-tags#:~:text=Click%20on%20this%20link) Should reload the page and highlight the link's text

Comment: Thanks! 7 years and 7 days later :)