# How to link to specific line of text in page, using only URL?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am curious if there is a way to use only a URL to send someone to a specific line at a given page. Citebite does this, however it links to a cached page instead of the actual live page. http://citebite.com/

You can also do something similar with PDF's where you give it a designated page #:
Link to page 6 in the listed pdf.
http://mises.org/journals/scholar/long.pdf#page=6

I have done a lot of looking and all I am finding are for embedding the link in HTML, which isn't what I'm after. Ideally I would like to be able to just send a URL that jumps to a specific line of text/ highlights it (exactly like Citebite does, but without having to use Citebite).

Comment: Are you trying to link to specific lines on your own pages, or other sites? You can use the anchor tag to do this, but only if you can add those anchor tags to the HTML you're linking to.

Comment: No they are not sites I would be able to modify the HTML tags.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338602/linking-to-arbitrary-content-on-a-webpage-without-anchor-tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the situation:

**1-Your own content**

**a.** Simply add a href id, and then send a link to that (http://exmaple.com/document.php#myLine)

**b.** For a more advanced solution, you can scroll to a specific area and highlight it using javascript, basically you call something like this:
http://example.com/document.php?scrollX=100&scrollY=230

and in your PHP code you have a function like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['scrollX']) && isset($_GET['scrollY')){
    ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           window.scrollTo(<?= $_GET['scrollX'];?>, <?=$_GET['scrollY'];?>);
       </script>
    <?
}
?>
```

You can also use JQuery and do more fancy things like highlighting text or changing CSS values depending on the arguments

**2-Someone else's content**

You cannot directly link to a specific line or area without a browser extension or an external service like [CiteBite](http://citebite.com/), however with some hackery you can build your own little service that displays the website and run your own JS on it (think iFrames or something like that)

Answer (score 6):

You must give an ID to your element. Example: `<div id="footer">Footer</div>`. If you go to `mypage.html#footer`, the browser will get you there.

If it's not your webpage, look in the code, you may find an ID element next to the text you want.

Answer (score 4):

There is [an experimental feature in Chrome 74](https://github.com/WICG/ScrollToTextFragment) called Scroll To Text Fragment which allows you to [specify phrases to be highlighted in a URL](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/).  We may have to wait a while before this becomes finalised and supported in browsers by default.

Meanwhile, if the article to which you want to link also has a PDF version, you could use a URL like `https://example.org/file.pdf#page=2&search=findme` to highlight `findme` on page 2.

Comment: This feature has since launched to stable in Chrome 80. Read more about it in the [article](https://web.dev/text-fragments/).

Comment: the 'page' works but 'search' not.

Comment: @Steven.Xi that might be because your PDF is using an image of text instead of real text.  If PDF viewers fail to find the text in search, then so will a search= URL.

Comment: @SilasS.Brown no, it's not. Try this link: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As far as my knowledge goes, you cannot do it natively without some sort of caching, plugins or addons or having full control over html where you can embed anchor tags.